# How do I overlap images using specific x and y values in android studio using XML?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have an imageview of a map that takes up the whole screen, and I'd like to put images on top of that one, but I'm not sure how to position them using coordinates in XML.

Comment: I think you might need an XML style sheet using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Here is an example XML file where there is some text on top of a map.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content -->
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- "Loaded" flash bar layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FlashBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp">
    <!-- flash bar content -->
</FrameLayout>
<!-- Last loaded time layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/UpdateTimeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
```

In your case you would just change the TextViews to Images and position them how you would any image in a layoutview.